# Passing an array as reference to a std::tuple

Tags: c++, c++11

I try to forward parameters (which may hold a reference to an array) to a tuple:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

#ifndef LOG_TYPE
#define LOG_TYPE(X) std::clog << typeid(X).name() << std::endl;
#endif

#ifndef LOG
#define LOG(X) std::clog << X << std::endl;
#endif

template <typename ... Parameters>
void pass(Parameters&& ... parameters) {
    auto tuple = std::forward_as_tuple(parameters ...);

    // std::tuple<int (&) [3]>
    LOG_TYPE(tuple);

    typedef typename std::tuple_element<0, decltype(tuple)>::type array_type;

    // int [3]
    LOG_TYPE(array_type);

    // --- The following is not the desired result ---    
    // array: 0
    LOG("array: " << std::is_array<array_type>());
}


template <typename ... Parameters>
void pass_ref(Parameters&& ... parameters) {
    auto tuple = std::forward_as_tuple(parameters ...);

    // std::tuple<std::reference_wrapper<int [3]>&>
    LOG_TYPE(tuple);

    typedef typename std::remove_reference<
        typename std::tuple_element<0, decltype(tuple)>::type>::type
        element_type;
    typedef typename element_type::type array_type;

    // int [3]
    LOG_TYPE(array_type);

    // array: 1
    LOG("array: " << std::is_array<array_type>());
}


int main() {
    int array[3];

    // array: 1
    LOG("array: " << std::is_array<decltype(array)>());

    // This is what I like:
    pass(array);
    // This works:
    pass_ref(std::ref(array));
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to get around `std::ref` ?

(Note: The question is not about logging, but the `std::is_array<array_type>()`)

Comment: Unrelated: you may want to forward the parameters into `forward_as_tuple`, otherwise you forward all lvalues and it's essentially the same as `std::tie` (so you want `std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Parameters>(parameters)...);`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`forward_as_tuple` constructs a tuple of references to the arguments ([link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/forward_as_tuple)) and a reference to an array is not an array. You can check by using `std::is_reference<T>`.

This seems to work:

```
template <typename ... Parameters>
void pass(Parameters& ... parameters) {
                   ^^^ no &&

    typedef std::tuple<Parameters...> tuple_type;
    LOG_TYPE(tuple);

    typedef typename std::tuple_element<0, tuple_type>::type array_type;

    // int [3]
    LOG_TYPE(array_type);

    // array: 0
    LOG("array: " << std::is_array<array_type>());
}
```

You can also modify your original code to drop the reference:

```
template <typename ... Parameters>
void pass(Parameters&& ... parameters) {
    auto tuple = std::forward_as_tuple(parameters ...);

    // std::tuple<int (&) [3]>
    LOG_TYPE(tuple);

    typedef typename std::tuple_element<0, decltype(tuple)>::type array_type_r;

    // >>> drop the reference added by forward_as_tuple
    typedef typename std::remove_reference<array_type_r>::type array_type;

    // int [3]
    LOG_TYPE(array_type);

    // array: 0
    LOG("array: " << std::is_array<array_type>());
}
```

Comment: Thanks both produce the desired result - I will go for the second

Answer (score 0):

```
#define LOG_TYPE(X) std::clog << typeid(X).name() << std::endl;
```

`typeid` is the wrong tool for inspecting this.

In the first function, `array_type` is not an array type because it is a reference type. The first element of `tuple<int(&)[3]>` is `int(&)[3]`, not `int[3]`. `typeid` doesn't care for top-level references, so it doesn't reflect that in that program's output.

I tend to use a construct like the following when I'm debugging template meta-programming code in order to convince the compiler to print out an exact type. Sadly it can only do so as an error message.

```
struct{}_ = foo; // where foo is a value of the type I want in the message
```

This yields something like "no conversion from  to anonymous structure". Sometimes I don't have a value readily available for this, so I use `std::declval` or a simple `template <typename T> struct show{};`.

So your fix is:

```
typedef typename std::remove_reference<
    typename std::tuple_element<0, decltype(tuple)>::type>::type array_type;
```